# The output is null, instead of the expected indices of the matching values

Tags: arrays, c, function-pointers

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    
    returnSize = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    int i, j;
    if(returnSize == NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++)
        {
            if((nums[i] + nums[j]) == target)
            {
                returnSize[0] = i;
                returnSize[1] = j;
                break;
            
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    return returnSize;
}
```

The values of `i` and `j` is not printing in the output. It is showing it null. The question was to output the index of the values whose sum is equal to any particular target.

Comment: Why are you solving leetcode problems in C? Problems on leetcode use complex data structures, and it is recommended to use a high-level language that has an inbuilt data structure library. If you are into C, then I would suggest you look into C++. C++ has STL, it allows you to use data structures flexibly. For the question you are solving above, your code is O(N^2) which is very slow. This can be optimized by using a hashtable or ```unordered_map``` in C++ STL. The optimized solution will have O(N) time complexity.

Comment: How are you calling this function?  Passing `returnSize` as an argument and then ignoring what is passed is weird.  It could easily lead to the calling code not seeing the allocated memory.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre], i.e. add a `main` function that calls `twoSum`, preferably with hard-coded data.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that `int *returnSize` is used to pass the size of returned array back to the caller because the target number could be a sum of more than two members (i. e. `3 + 4 = 7` or `1 + 2 + 5 = 7`)

Comment: Without seeing the calling function we can only guess that `int* returnSize` is intended as an output parameter which does not work as expected because the modified pointer value is not passed back to the caller. There is no reference in the question for your assumption that the function might be expected to check the sum of more than 2 numbers.